# What is the order of the derivative function $f'$

Tags: complex-analysis

The order of an entire function $f(·)$ is the smallest $r>0$ such that
$|f(z)| <e^{(|z|^{r+ε})}$ for all $ε > 0$.
Let $f$ be an entire function of order $r= 1$. My **question** is: What is the order of the derivative function $f'$. Is it finite or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ and $f'$ have the *same* order. See for example Boas: *Entire functions*, Academic Press.

Comment: @ mrf: Yes, The order of an entire function $f(·)$ is the smallest $r>0$ such that $f(z) <exp(|z|^{r+ε})$ for all $ε > 0$.

Comment: @RH1 I don't understand the point of your comment. I'm aware of the definition of the order of an entire function.

Comment: @ mrf: Yes, and thank you vey much.